# Not implement all methods in sub class

Tags: scala, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, traits

Let's say we have `private[feature] trait ImputerParams extends Params`.

I then have `class Imputer extend ImputerParams`.

My question is do I need to implement all methods in `Params`? According to the documentation of Scala, I should. However, as I am reading the real production code, I found `Imputer` does not implement all methods from `Params`, and it works well. So I am confused.

If I want to learn more, what topics should I read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class that extends a trait has to implement all abstract function definitions, that is, the functions that are defined without a body.

However, a trait in Scala can contain functions with a full implementation, and then there's no requirement to override them.

```
trait Foo {
  def bar(): Int
  def add(x: Int) = x + 1
}
```

In this example, a class extending `Foo` will have to override and implement `bar`, but not `add`.